# Powershell or similar to run all test suites of a test plan

Tags: automated-testing, mstest, mtm, tfs2010, powershell

Does anybody have a powershell to run all test cases of all test suites in a test plan? I want a simple way of running all test cases of a test plan despite of their state (Active, Failed, etc).

MTM does not have such functionality.

I am using Microsoft Test Manager 2013 with Team Foundation Server 2013.

Answer (score 1):

MS has several command line tools that will run tests. There's more information about how to use them and how to choose the tool you use on the MSDN site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx

I'd suggest reading the documentation and experimenting with the different tools to decide which of the tools works best for your situation.